# Multi module Scala Play 2.3 conf location

Tags: scala, playframework, configuration

I've been tasked with rewriting an old ant build script to SBT. As it happens, our suite is built up of 3 modules:

- A Play 2.3 front-end webserver;
- A back-end for retrieving data from various other systems;
- A middle module containing some shared classes for database access and business logic.

Below an excerpt of my Build.scala file can be found:

```
val sharedSettings = Seq(
  organization        := <organization here>,
  version             := "1.2.5",
  scalaVersion        := "2.11.1",
  libraryDependencies ++= libraries,
  unmanagedJars in Compile ++= baseDirectory.value / "lib",
  unmanagedJars in Compile ++= baseDirectory.value / "src",
  unmanagedJars in Compile ++= baseDirectory.value / "test"
)

lazy val middle = project.settings(sharedSettings: _*)
lazy val back = project.settings(sharedSettings: _*).dependsOn(middle)

lazy val front =
  project
    .enablePlugins(play.PlayScala)
    .settings(sharedSettings: _*)
    .settings(scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "app")
    .settings(
      routesImport ++= Seq(
        "scala.language.reflectiveCalls", // Removes warnings when using multiple routes files
        "com.asml.cerberus.front.toolbox.Binders._")
    )
    .dependsOn(middle % "compile->compile;test->test")
```

I've got my application.conf in the ./front/conf/ directory. Unfortunately, if I now run sbt, it looks for a ./conf/application.conf file. (I've tested this by moving the conf directory.)

Is there any way how I can tell SBT/Play to use the front module's conf directory in stead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case that helps, we have a wrapper script around activator (sbt) activatorWrapper:

```
#!/bin/bash

activator -Dconfig.file=front/conf/application.conf
```

Then you can start your application with :

```
$ ./activatorWrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use system properties to specify an alternative config file. See [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ProductionConfiguration#Specifying-an-alternate-configuration-file) for the details.

Comment: This isn't really an option since we are using a library that need some initialization (which we do in the Global object). When we run sbt test, this command line argument is ignored, and hence the Global object will not initialize the library.

Comment: How are you setting the property? You can add it your `build.sbt` as follows `javaOptions += "-Dconfig.file=/opt/conf/prod.conf"}"`